# Running EMR example, getting 301 Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, emr, amazon-emr

I am trying to run example hadoop-streaming command:

```
hadoop-streaming -files streamingCode/wordSplitter.py \
-mapper wordSplitter.py \
-input s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input \
-output streamingCode/wordCountOut \
-reducer aggregate
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Moved Permanently (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 98038E504E150CEC), S3 Extended Request ID: IW1x5otBSepAnPgW/RKELCUI9dhADQvrXqU2Ase1CLIa0SWDFnBbTscXihrvHvNm2ZRxjjSJZ1Q=
```

I think that it is because my cluster is in `us-west-2`, but i can't figure out how to properly format the `s3` url (or perhaps that is not the issue at all).

Edit: After changing it to the following url:

```
s3://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input
```

I am now getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3
Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: BC8DB415C780DF84), 
           S3 Extended Request ID: sx8W/+gvND2ssqQce9ZQsZTiqxmSJYZs8OiXgrjwL3dm0JRPaC7ceHor+yrHsPuKTjM2LUwkRAw=
```

Edit: So I have confirmed that the error is indeed because my cluster is in `us-west-2`, I have created a cluster in `us-east-1` and it works properly. So, the question is how do I access a s3 bucket from another region? Is this even possible?

Comment: got to any solution to this one ?

Comment: I think that particular bucket is only accessible from us-east-1

Comment: that doesn't sound correct, buckets are accessible based on permissions

Comment: @GauravShah try using the following url instead:

elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/wordcount/input

Answer (score 1):

Amazon changed the default behavior starting emr-4.7.0 which caused this error when we upgraded EMR versions.

Solution is simple, add this configuration to core-site:
fs.s3n.endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: This has been improved and will now work across regions without the need to change endpoint starting with emr-5.1.0.